# Spring Data REST select fields at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS in my project.
My domain model is quite complex and I'd like to follow some of [REST best practice as the fields selection](https://medium.com/@mwaysolutions/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api-33a25a4e92c1).

I do know [Spring projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) but I'm looking for a way to tell what fields I need from the client at runtime. Simple as call `GET /cars?fields=manufacturer,model,id,color`.

Because I'd like to take advantage of Spring Data, I think I should create something in between the REST call and Spring. 
Do you know some good resource/example to create something like that?

Comment: an example https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/entity-filtering-selectable, not spring

Comment: That's what GraphQL was invented for: https://graphql.org/learn/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I know GraphQL and I already use it. It's very useful but I don't like some things about it, so I'd like rather to lean more on REST.

Answer (score 5):

With  Squiggly Filter

```
@GetMapping(value="cars")
public @ResponseBody List<Car> getCars(@RequestParam("fields") String fields){
List<Car> carList ;
-------
ObjectMapper mapper = = Squiggly.init(new ObjectMapper(), fields);  
System.out.println(SquigglyUtils.stringify(mapper, carList));
-------
}
```

More on,

https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly-java

With `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`,

Car class,

```
@JsonFilter("myfilter")
public class Car {
    public String color;
    public String model;
    public String type;
```

At controller,

```
@GetMapping(value = "/cars")
public ResponseEntity<?> getCars(@RequestParam("fields") String fields) throws IOException {
        List<Car> list = Arrays.asList(new Car("pink", "verna", "sedan"), new Car("black", "i10", "hatchback"),
                new Car("voilet", "brizza", "SUV"));
        SimpleFilterProvider  filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myfilter",
                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(fields.split(",")));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setFilterProvider(filterProvider);;
        return new ResponseEntity<>(mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(list),Object.class), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. How am I supposed to set fields when i do a GET? jgen.getOutputContext().getCurrentName() returns 'content'.